# Shell script and quote in path

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, quotes

I have a simple shell script.  Currently it looks as below.  The diff command fails with "No such file or directory" on the second argument (the one in red below).

```
#!/bin/bash
    
set -x

cd "/Volumes/$1/Backups.backupdb/SkiAddict’s Mac/Latest"
time diff -qr /Users/n/Documents/Code "SkiAddict’s Mac/Users/n/Documents/Code"
```

I call the script like this from the Terminal:

```
bash myScript.sh Quadra
```

To get the first command (cd) to work, it turned out that unless the quote character in "SkiAddict's" was a smart quote, and I got the same error (*No such file or directory*).  Now that line is working fine and even if I copy the text from that line and paste it into the diff command, it doesn't work.

This entire script was copied from an already-working [QuicKeys](https://www.macworld.com/article/205119/quickeys4_review.html) macro which types the text into a Terminal window, so I really figured making a shell script wouldn't be a biggie.  The macro begins by "typing" this line into a new Terminal tab:

```
cd /Volumes/Quadra/Backups.backupdb/SkiAddict’s\ Mac/Latest
```

It then presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> and "types" this line:

```
time diff -qr /Users/n/Documents/Code "SkiAddict's Mac/Users/n/Documents/Code"
```

Again, it then presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  The thing works perfectly.

I've tried double quotes at either end, single quotes at either end, escaping the quote, both with and without double or single quotes at either end.  Nothing works.

What should I do?

Comment: But the `cd` line works with the un-escaped space in `SkiAddicts's Mac`?

Comment: Also, the 'apostrophe' in `SkiAddict's Mac` still looks like a smartquote to me.  Shouldn't it be a regular apostrophe, like `this'n`?

Comment: Oops, my bad.  In fact the line with the cd command has double quotes.  The version above was a left-over from a version of this post which I wrote earlier, while I was fighting to get the cd command to work.  (The rest of the script was copied from the current version.)  The smart quote was the only thing that worked on that line.  I find it weird too, which is why it took so long to realise that the unsmart quote was what was causing the problem.  BUT the smart quote for the diff command does not work.

Comment: No, it's really like that in my Terminal.  I just manually copied and pasted them from the QuicKeys window into the Terminal, and one comes out smart and the other doesn't.  The diff is proceeding like a lamb right now :-)

Comment: All else I can think of is to put some `echo` commands in your script to see if it's expanding the quotes and escapes as you expect.  Just replace the `time diff` with `echo` and if it prints out the paths as you would want them to be run, then I have no other ideas.

Comment: Please open a Terminal and type (or copy/paste) `cd "/Volumes/Quadra/Backups.backupdb/SkiAddict’s Mac/Latest"; ls -l`. What output do you get?

Comment: I tried to simulate this on my Mac (I didn't rename my hard drive, but I created directories `mkdir -p "SkiAddict’s Mac/Users/n/Documents/Code" "Backups.backupdb/SkiAddict’s Mac/Latest"` and copied some files into them, edited one of the files, and ran `diff -qr "./SkiAddict’s Mac/Users/n/Documents/Code" "./Backups.backupdb/SkiAddict’s Mac/Latest"` in both `ksh` and `bash` and it worked fine.  You do have a difference between `'` and `’` in your 'working from the terminal' code — those are very different characters and might account for the 'directory not found' problem.

Answer (score 1):

To see what your script is actually doing, put some [echo](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) commands in your script to see if it's expanding the quotes and escapes as you expect. Just replace the `time diff` with `echo` and if it prints out the paths differently from how you would want them to be run, modify them accordingly.

---

I think actually the second file you're trying to open probably *doesn't* exist.  It's most likely that that the path you want is:

```
/Users/n/Documents/Code
```

On Unix (or Mac) machine, all paths start in the 'root' directory, also know simply as:

```
/
```

Not the 'name' of your computer, which for you is `SkiAddict's Mac`

---

On the other hand, if you're actually trying to access a directory in the `TimeMachine` volume, you need to have a relative path, which might just simply be incorrect in your script.  Try using the full path, starting with `/Volumes/...` in the `diff` line.  As it stands, after the `cd` this is the file it will try to compare to:

```
"/Volumes/$1/Backups.backupdb/SkiAddict’s Mac/Latest/SkiAddict’s Mac/Users/n/Documents/Code"
```

You can determine what the correct path should be by typing `cd /Volu...` into your terminal and using tab-completion until you are on the `TimeMachine`.  The tab-completion will properly escape spaces and special characters and will find an existing path.  Perhaps this will help you find the error in your pathname.

Comment: Unless the second file for the `diff` is supposed to be relative to the directory you just `cd`ed into?

Comment: No, that doesn't work either.  I tried that and all it achieves is to get diff to compare the folder in the first argument to itself :-)  In any case, I know the folder in the second argument works because if I trigger the QuicKeys macro, it works perfectly.

Comment: So the path for the second file is on the `TimeMachine` volume?  And that pathname has `SkiAddict's Mac` in it twice?

Comment: no it's not supposed to be relative to that directory.  I have to use cd first because this is a TimeMachine backup and the Mac is very picky about what can and can't be done in there.  The only way I've found to get the backup verified is by doing the two steps as listed above.  I'm going to edit my original post to show the exact text that the QuicKeys macro contains.

Comment: Well if the pathname doesn't start with `/` or `../` it will assume it starts with `./` and will look in the current directory for that filename.

Comment: I just tried changing the argument for diff to `"/SkiAddict’s Mac/Users/n/Documents/Code"`, same error.

Comment: `"/Volumes/SkiAddict’s Mac/Users/n/Documents/Code"` also doesn't work.

Comment: Just to emphasise the point, this all works when typed (or "typed") into a Terminal window.  It's only the moving to a shell script which is causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [the Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) I was able to learn about $'...' (thus `$'SkiAddict\'s` below). This enables the single quote in the path to be backslashed, which makes the [`diff`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) command happy.

And no, the `cd` command cannot be treated in the same way.  If I change anything about that line, it doesn't work again!!! Sigh...

So, the two lines look like this:

```
cd "/Volumes/$1/Backups.backupdb/SkiAddict’s Mac/Latest"
time diff -qr /Users/n/Documents/Code $'SkiAddict\'s Mac/Users/n/Documents/Code'
```