# Quoting a path in linux

Tags: bash

I am learning shell scripting and created a script. In the script I have assigned find command output to a variable in my code. But reviewer commented that "paths need quoting since they contain variables that need to be expanded". I am not getting this.

```
MAIN_PROFILE="$(find /Users/$CURRENT_USER/Library/Group\ Containers/*.Office -type d -name "Main Profile")"
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the quotes *inside* the path variable?  `\"Main Profile\"` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shell script and quote in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048700/shell-script-and-quote-in-path)

Answer (score 2):

You could quote `$CURRENT_USER` like this :

```sh
MAIN_PROFILE="$(find /Users/"$CURRENT_USER"/Library/Group\ Containers/*.Office -type d -name "Main Profile")"
```

You need to do it to prevent word splitting or globbing (See https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086)

For example with a script like this :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
USER="jean claude"
find /home/"$USER"/ -type d -name "test"
```

It will work perfectly.

But if you unquote it :

```sh
find: ‘/home/jean’: No such file or directory
find: ‘claude/’: No such file or directory
```

You could also quote the full path as your reviewer said, so you wouldn't have to escape spaces :

```sh
MAIN_PROFILE="$(find "/Users/$CURRENT_USER/Library/Group Containers/"*.Office -type d -name "Main Profile")"
```